# Excel 2007 Sumproduct foreach day in column?

Tags: excel-formula

I currently have a spread sheet will be populated without a set size when it comes to row count. I have a column for time that is populated ever time an entry is made.

Ex:

```
Transition Time     State     Reason Code   Duration
06/01/2015 06:43 AM Logged-in   0           0:00:00
06/01/2015 06:43 AM Not Ready   32760       0:00:43
06/01/2015 06:44 AM Logout      5           0:00:00
06/01/2015 06:46 AM Logged-in   0           0:00:00
06/01/2015 06:46 AM Not Ready   32760       0:01:47
06/01/2015 06:47 AM Ready       0           0:00:00
06/01/2015 06:47 AM Reserved    0           0:00:06
06/01/2015 06:48 AM Talking     0           0:06:59
06/01/2015 06:55 AM Not Ready   6           0:02:58
06/01/2015 06:58 AM Ready       0           0:00:00
06/01/2015 06:58 AM Reserved    0           0:00:01
06/01/2015 06:58 AM Talking     0           0:09:18
06/01/2015 07:07 AM Work        0           0:00:05
```

Now this will continue all the way through the report. Generally it is a month long, but can be longer. I was able to get the values for the month based on other columns.

Ex:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C:C=6),--(B:B="Not Ready"),(D:D))
```

This will give me the whole reports value. I need to get this where it will count for 1 day at a time.

pseudo:

```
DateTime selectedDay = current row
DateTime currentDay = current day from row;

foreach(DateTime day in Transition Time)
{
    if(selectedDay <= currentDay)
    {
        //SUM to CELL - Array prefered
    }
    else if(selectedDay > currentDay)
    {
       currentDay = selectedDay
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following formula to calculate total duration in seconds for total users "Not Ready" with Reason Code 6 on a particular day set by date in cell `H2`:

```
{=(SUM(IF(((B:B="Not Ready")*(IFERROR(INT(A:A),0)=H2)*(C:C=6))=1,TIMEVALUE(D:D),0)))*86400}
```

Please note that the curly brackets are not inputed manually but when entering formula as array formula using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`.

I have taken advantage of being able to multiply booleans (true or false, 1 or 0) as `AND` was calculating throughout the whole array. This gives me a 1 for rows where all conditions are met. Using an `IF(array=1,"Duration range")` I'm able to extract all relevant values and with which I `SUM` throughout the final array and multiply by 86400 (number of seconds in a day) to arrive at the final calculation. Regards,